# Getting texts within <li><a> in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the text within

```html
<li><a href="">Navi</a><li>
```

back using Javascript.

```js
var clickedTopPlayer = function()
{

 var player = this.innerHTML;

 var parsed = player.innerHTML();

 loadResults(parsed);

    return false;
};
$('li').on("click", clickedTopPlayer);
```

The code I tried to do this with wouldn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: *wouldn't work* - what is `loadResults` and what concretely doesn't work?

Comment: loadResults just accepts the string and prints it out on html.  The part that doesn't work was trying to get "Navi" out of the html.  This problem is solved by innerText thanks to baao's tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `innerText` property:

```
var clickedTopPlayer = function() {
    var player = this.innerText;
    loadResults(player);
    return false;
};

$('li').on("click", clickedTopPlayer);
```

See here:

```js
var clickedTopPlayer = function() {
  var player = this.innerText;
  console.log(player);
};

$('li').on("click", clickedTopPlayer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a>Foo</a>
</li>
```

Also note that `innerHTML` is never a function - as you used it as one here

```
var parsed = player.innerHTML();
```